# Why am I getting OperationalError?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table in the admin. It works on sqlite3, but doesnt work on postgresql

I get an error:

(psycopg2.OperationalError)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
psycopg2.OperationalError:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\adfaf\Desktop\accountParser\main.py", line 125, in 
db.create_all()

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

i wrote this code

```
`from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://username:password@localhost/account"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asd'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)



@app.route("/", methods = ['POST'])
def mainPage():
    return "hello"



class Accounts(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "accounts"

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  api_key = db.Column(db.Text(60))
  search_engine_id = db.Column(db.Text(60))



admin = Admin(app, name="ADMIN", template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(ModelView(Accounts, db.session, name="Аккаунты"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
  app.run(debug=True)`
```

What can i do? Help pls

Comment: @python_user, unfortunately that's all what i got

Comment: @python_user, the same situation

Comment: @python_user, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpSPb.png

Comment: sorry, im dumb DB name should be "postgres", not "account